# Output of Ajax response

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jsp

My jsp page contains an array of food with 4 items in it.

When the user enters a food name in the text box which exists in the array I get a output with 4 strings stating whether it is found or not.

Depending on the position of the food item in the array I get the actual answer in the respective string. If the food item entered is the 4th element in array then 4th string written by AJAX gives the correct answer.

My screenshots show the issue

showing the output in case the value entered is Samosa Pav,the second string gives the right output.

[image: eg showing the output in case the value entered is Samosa Pav,the second string gives the right output]

showing the output in case the value entered is misalPav,the fourth string gives the right output

[image: showing the output in case the value entered is misalPav,the fourth string gives the right output]

What changes so I need to make to ensure that only one and the correct output is received from AJAX call?

```js
var request;

function sendInfo() {
  var v = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
  var url = "index.jsp?food=" + v;

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  if (request.readyState == 0 || request.readyState == 4) {
    try {
      request.onreadystatechange = getInfo;
      request.open("GET", url, true);
      request.send();
    } catch (e) {
      alert("Unable to connect to server");
    }
  }
}

function getInfo() {
  if (request.readyState == 4) {
    if (request.status == 200) {
      var val = request.responseText;
      document.getElementById('underInput').innerHTML = val;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="food.js">


  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h3>The Chuff Bucket</h3>
  Enter the food you want to order

  <input type="text" id="userInput" name="input" onkeyup="sendInfo()"></input>

  <div id="underInput"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

```
%-- 
Document   : index
Created on : 15 Dec, 2016, 7:07:55 PM
Author     : KRISHNAJI
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<%   
  String food = request.getParameter("food");
  String foodArray[] = {"Vada Pav", "Samosa Pav", "Pav Bhaji", "Misal Pav"};

  for(int i = 0; i < foodArray.length; i++)
  {
    if(food.equalsIgnoreCase(foodArray[i]))
    {
      out.println("Hey we do have " + food);
    }
    else if (food == "")
    {
      out.println("Enter a food");
    }
    else
    {
      out.println("We don't have " + food);
    }
  }
%>
</body>
</html>




[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBHnZ.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xv7fG.jpg
```

Comment: Perhaps you could try to put break statements after your prints. The look iterates over the entire array, all 4 items and prints once for each item.

Comment: Thanks Douglas, using break after print statement in if elseif and else is giving me correct output only if the textbox is blank or if I enter the First item in the array.
Kindly edit the .jsp file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will just edit the important bits here:

```
String food = request.getParameter("food");
String foodArray[] = {"Vada Pav", "Samosa Pav", "Pav Bhaji", "Misal Pav"};

int i = 0;

for(i = 0; i < foodArray.length; i++)
{
  if(food.equalsIgnoreCase(foodArray[i]))
  {
    out.println("Hey we do have " + food);
    break;
  }
  else if (food == "")
  {
    out.println("Enter a food");
    break;
  }
}

if(i >= foodArray.length)
{
  out.println("We don't have " + food);
}
```

Right, in my comment I forgot that all other conditions in your original loop will still print because of the else statement. So I now declared your counter outside of the loop and compared to the length of the array after the loop is exited. That way, if the food they entered is not found, it will only print once at the end. If input is blank, or matches a food, the conditions will be met and it will print the correct response. The counter will cease to increment and will be less than the length of the array, failing the last condition, and leaving you with only the correct response. This should answer your question fully.